# Jenkins : how to declare environments variables securely in JenkinsFile with GitHub webhook?

Tags: github, jenkins, amazon-ec2, terraform, jenkins-pipeline

I'm beginner with Jenkins and I must build a Jenkins Pipeline for a project. I decided to use GitHub as SCM. GitHub launch Jenkins pipeline thanks to webhook on each push.

The Jenkins pipeline is a multibranche pipeline. So I can have one Jenkinsfile on each GitHub branch.

I also use Terraform to build EC2 Instance on AWS thanks to my Jenkins pipeline. So I must manage my IAM credentials and some other important variables that I can be able to use during the workflow.

How can I secure my variables during the workflow ? My jenkinsfile is versioned on Github. If I use the "env" step in JenkinsFile, all my variables will be visible. GitHub doesn't allow to manage environment variable if I didn't use GitHub Action. I don't now if a Jenkins plugin can help me or a function that I not know on Jenkins ? I know the global environment variables on Jenkins but all my variables are focused on one project and not on all.

Thank you for your help.
Gati

Comment: Hi @Gati, Sorry I didn't get your query. What exactly is the question here?

Comment: Hi, I would like to know how I can throw variables in Jenkins pipeline without write variables values on my Jenkinsfile which will be versionned on GitHub ?

Comment: You can store it in Jenkins credentials if the environment variables you are refering to contains any tokens.